# warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘strlen’ int strlen (char *pstr);

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am writing a code for my beginner coding class in which we are creating our own `strlen`, `strcat`, `strcmp`, and `strcpy` functions. I have created the `strlen` function and attempted to use it in my code. I have a user enter a string and store that in a character string and then send the string to a function which has a pointer as a parameter and the function then returns the length of the string. The problem I get when I compile the code is this message:

```
    warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘strlen’
 int strlen (char *pstr);
```

I do not have a lot of experience and I do not quite understand what the compiler message is trying to tell me other than I messed something up. Can someone explain the problem to me as well as what I should do to fix it?

Here is my prototype for the function:

```
int strlen (char *pstr);
```

Here is the function itself:

```
int strlen (char *pstr)
{
    int counter;

    for ( ; pstr != '\0'; pstr++)
    {
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;

}
```

And here is the call to the function within my code:

```
char string1[SIZE], string2[SIZE];
int len1, len2;

len1 = strlen (string1);
len2 = strlen (string2);
printf("The length of string 1 is: %d", len1);
printf("The length of string 2 is: %d", len2);
```

Comment: If you do a certain `#include` you'll get the standard definition. Even so, the correct definition is `size_t strlen(const char *str)`. The `const` is a good idea. If you include something else, you may get this, or the compiler will try to inline from the standard function. Maybe try renaming your version to something like: `mystrlen`, etc. to avoid the conflict. The advantage is that you can write a unit test to compare your version against the standard one.

Comment: Just a word of caution: you need to initialize your `counter` variable since it's a local one, other wise you won't get a predictable behavior, because it's value can be anything upon declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says there is already a function with that name, and it is declared differently (the standard `strlen`, of course).

You need to either use a different name, or simply not include the standards (remove potential `#include ...` lines from your code.

Also, you have two bugs in your function:

1. the comparison in the loop needs to compare not the pointer to `'\0'`, but the char where it points to: `for ( ; *pstr != '\0'; pstr++)`
2. The counter is not initialized. It might start with 6754836or any othe random number, and you are incrementing from there. Set it to 0 in the declaration:`int counter=0;`

Comment: You are not allowed to redefine `strlen`, period. Doesn't matter whether you `#include`d anything. See **Reserved Identifiers**: "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) **are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage**." (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: removing `include` s is bad advice. The code is undefined behaviour regardless of what is included; and since any standard header may include any other you cannot control this anyway.